# How to solve nth degree equation in php?

Tags: php, math, equation-solving

How to solve nth degree equations in PHP

**Example:**

> 1/(1+i)+1/(1+i)<sup>2</sup>+...1/(1+i)<sup>n</sup>=k

While k is the constant,I'd like to find value of i.

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: those who are down voting please post reasons and comment links if already has answer please this is a request

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your expression on the left is a geometric sum, so you can rewrite it as (using `x=1+i`)

```
1/x*(1+...+1/x^(n-1)) = 1/x * (1-1/x^n)/(1-1/x) = (1-x^(-n))/(x-1)
```

and consequently the equation can be rewritten as

```
(1 - pow( 1+i, -n))/i = k
```

Now from the original expression one knows that the left side as a sum of convex monotonically decreasing functions is equally so, thus any of bisection, regula falsi variants or secant method will work sufficiently well.

Use

```
(1+i)^(-n)=1 - n*i + (n*(n+1))/2*i^2 +...
```

to get the approximative equation and first approximation

```
1-(n+1)/2*i = k/n  <=> i = (1-k/n)*2/(n+1)
```

so that you can start bracketing method with the interval from `0` to twice this `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this....

```
$n = 5;
$i = 2;
$k = null;

for ($x = 1; $x <= $n; $x++) {
    $k += 1 / pow((1 + $i), $x);
}

echo $k; //Answer --> 0.49794238683128
```

Comment: Could you clarify, please, how this method solves the problem? In the original post `k` is given and `i` is unknown.

Comment: This logic solves for `k` provided `i` is given... Ok, let me try to find `i`.